# Error displaying the error page: The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform.: The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform

Tags: cache

I have installed Joomla 3.6 in ubuntu 16.4.

but after installation of Joomla, I see the following error:

> **Error displaying the error page:** The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform.: The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform.

please help me

Comment: pls check folder permissions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank You my friends
for slove this problem, im use the fllow code:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/myjoomla/administrator/cache
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/myjoomla/cache
```

Thank You - AD@Body

Answer (score 1):

The permissions on the `/cache` and `/administrator/cache` need to be writable.

Permissions can usually be updated via the file manager in your hosting control panel e.g. cPanel.